# Как еще найти сумму всех целых нечетных чисел в диапазоне, указанном пользователе?

Tags: c++, циклы, оптимизация

Написать программу, которая находит сумму всех целых нечетных чисел в диапазоне, указанном пользователе.

```
#include<iostream>:
using namespace std;
int main()

setlocale(LC_ALL, "rus");
int val1; // начало диапазона
int val2; // конец диапазона
int sum = 0; // переменная хранящая сумму
cout << "Укажите диапозон чисел:\nПервое число: " << endl;
cin >> val1;
cout << "Второе число: " << endl;
cin >> val2;
while (val1 <= val2)
{
    if (val1 % 2 != 0)
    {
        sum += val1;
    }
    val1++;
}

cout << "Результат: " << sum;
```

Как сделать так чтобы не каждый раз проверять четность числа, а проверить это перед циклом один раз, если четное, то прибавить единицу. А в цикле уже ничего не проверять, а просто прибавлять двойку к числу? Так можно оптимизировать код, но я не знаю как это сделать

Comment: Ну так вы же только что описали что надо делать. Ну и сделайте хотя бы попытку.

Comment: я несколько часов делаю попытки, но что-то в коде постоянно идет не так и я не могу понять как именно должно выглядеть это решение

Comment: Экономия на спичках какая-то, вместо того чтобы посчитать разность четных краев и сумму - см. ответ MBo.

Comment: оптимизировать можно только по какому-то параметру(кол-во памяти, объем исходного кода, скорость работы и тп)

Answer (score 5):

```
int sum(int a, int b)
{
    a = (a-(a&1))/2;
    b = (b+(b&1))/2;
    return b*b - a*a;
}
```

Передавать в функцию значения так, чтоб `a <= b`...

Comment: а зачем так сложно? `(a-(a&1))/2` -> `a/2` `(b+(b&1))/2` -> `(b+1)/2`

Comment: @pavel Потому что если просто — неверно... См. https://ideone.com/192kom, вашим методом — последний столбец

Comment: вопрос как быстрей _  безусловное выполнение арифметической операции  или  выполнение  более легкой операции при условии, типа  if(a&1)  --a /= 2?

Comment: @Harry а, я про отрицательные числа не подумал.

Answer (score 3):

Если действительно нужно оптимизировать, то вспомним, как в 7 классе изучали арифметическую прогрессию. И циклов не надо.

```
val1 += (1 - val1 & 1);
val2 -= (1 - val2 & 1);
return (val2 - val1 + 2) * (val1 + val2) / 4;
```

Первые строчки меняют чётные числа на большее и меньшее нечётные.

Comment: Ой, не стыкуется... Взгляните на https://ideone.com/DxF2Fi — первый и второй столбец - числа, третий - мои результаты, четвертый - "в лоб", пятый - ваши...

Comment: @Harry `a b c d e -> a b c e d` - не надо так путать )

Comment: Мда, еле углядел, что дело в отрицательных числах

Comment: @MBo Ага, остаток для отрицательного числа отрицательный...

Answer (score 0):

```
#include<iostream>:
using namespace std;

setlocale(LC_ALL, "rus");
int val1; // начало диапозона
int val2; // конец диапозона
int sum = 0; // переменная хранящая сумму
cout << "Укажите диапозон чисел:\nПервое число: " << endl;
cin >> val1;
cout << "Второе число: " << endl;
cin >> val2;
if(val1%2!=0)
{
    val1++
}
while (val1 <= val2)
{
    if (val1 % 2 != 0)
    {
        sum += val1;
    }
    val1++;
}

cout << "Результат: " << sum;
```

Comment: Неправильный ответ, если брать 1 и 5, то выдает 8, а правильная сумма нечетных 9 (1+3+5)

Comment: я поменял if (val1%2!=0) на (val1%2==0) и код стал работать. Это точно оптимизирует код?

Comment: @Валерий оптимизировать такой код трудно, ведь итак c++ быстрый язык, если вы решаете задачу на скорость, то ищите другой подход к решению, так как это - самый быстрый вариант, вашего способа.

Answer (score 0):

```
   #include<iostream>:
using namespace std;

void main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "rus");
    int val1; // начало диапозона
    int val2; // конец диапозона
    int sum = 0; // переменная хранящая сумму
    cout << "Укажите диапозон чисел:\nПервое число: " << endl;
    cin >> val1;
    cout << "Второе число: " << endl;
    cin >> val2;
    if (val1 % 2  == 0)
    {
        val1++;
    }
    while (val1 <= val2)
    {
            sum += val1;
            val1 += 2;
    }

    cout << "Результат: " << sum;
    
    
}
```

Я нашел правильный ответ